# Can I hide remote repository URL when pushing to remote server from git output?

Tags: git, bitbucket

When pushing to remote repository git output show repository URL like this:

[image: hide remote repository URL when pushing to remote server]

It is possible to hide URL from output.

Comment: In Gitlab, one can disable printing such url in the repository merge-request settings. Maybe it's the same in bitbucket repository settings.

Comment: Every line prefixed with `remote:` came from something that's *not Git*. It's that something (whatever it is) that you will need to control here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible (extreme) workaround would be to navigate to your Bitbucket Account's Settings (Avatar(Bottom Left) `> Bitbucket Settings > Account settings`)

[image: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/files/939922948/939922945/1/1510318930828/image2017-11-10+21%3A1%3A3.png]

And deselect the `Enable Console message` option:

[image: options -- https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/files/939922948/939922947/1/1510318930728/image2017-11-10+21%3A1%3A27.png]

You should no longer see the remote Bitbucket pull request message, meaning no more remote URL.